# Why does http.get take so long in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers

Using NodeJS and *http.get*, I am trying to see if a website uses a redirect. I tried a few URLs which all worked great. However, when I ran the code with washingtonpost.com it took over 5 seconds. In my browser the website works just fine. What could be the issue?

```
console.time("Done. Script executed in");
const http = require("http");

function checkRedirectHttp(input){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        http.get(input, {method: 'HEAD'}, (res) => { resolve([res.headers.location, res.statusCode]) })
            .on('error', (e) => { throw {Error: `Cannot reach website ${input}`} });
    }); 
};

checkRedirectHttp("http://www.washingtonpost.com/").then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    console.timeEnd("Done. Script executed in");
})
```

Output:

```
[
  'http://www.washingtonpost.com/gdpr-consent/?next_url=https%3a%2f%2fwww.washingtonpost.com%2f',
  302
]
Done. Script executed in: 8.101s
```

Comment: FYI, you aren't handling errors properly.  You should be calling `reject(e)` if you get an error, but you  have to declare the reject argument in `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...})` too.  Your `throw` will be asynchronous and won't be caught by the promise.

Comment: Thanks, I have to admit it took me quite a while to understand promises (currently learning NodeJS in my free time). I fixed it now and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code, enhanced it some and slowly added back the actual headers that are sent from my browser when I go to the same link in the browser.  When I changed the request to a "GET" (no longer a "HEAD") and added the following headers from my browser:

```
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36",
            "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "cookie": "a very long cookie here"
```

then the response went from 9 seconds to 71ms.

So, apparently the server doesn't like the HEAD request and doesn't like that  a bunch of headers it expects to be there are missing.  Probably, it is detecting that this isn't a real browser and it's either analyzing something for 8 seconds or it's just purposely delaying a response to a "fake client".

Also, if you use the `http://www.washingtonpost.com` URL instead of `https://www.washingtonpost.com`, it redirects to https every time for me.  So, you may as well just start with the `https://` form of the URL.

Comment: Thanks, would have never come up with this myself. Appreciate it!